# How to fix array printing multiple times

Tags: java, for-loop

When I run this method and set the text on the countLabel it prints it 26 times. Could anyone explain *why this happens* and *how to fix this problem*?

```
void updateCounts() {
    int[] letterCounts = new int[26];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        letterCounts[i] = 0;
    }

    String s = encrypted.getText();
    s = s.toUpperCase();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int j = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".indexOf(s.charAt(i));
        if (j >= 0) {
            letterCounts[j] += 1;
        }
    }

    String countString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        String n = Arrays.toString(letterCounts);

        if (n.equals("0")) {
            countString = countString + "   ";
        } else if (n.length() == 1) {
            countString = countString + " " + n + " ";
        } else {
            countString = countString + n + " ";
        }
    }

    String noCommas = countString.replace(',', ' ');
    countLabel.setText(noCommas.replace('0', ' '));
    System.out.println(noCommas.replace(',', ' '));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi ExtremelyAverageProgrammer,

In the method you have provided, the output only occurs once right at the end:

```
System.out.println(noCommas.replace(',', ' '));
```

What this means is that in your main method, you are calling the method "updateCounts()" 26 times, which would explain the irregular output.

Hopefully this helps!